# Cross Validation for Recommender System

Tags: recommendation-engine, rapidminer

I'm trying to do a 10 fold cross validation on a content-based recommender system. The data set consists of users id, movies id and ratings and the attribute set of movies id and attributes id, one for each genre. My problem as displayed below is at the train process of the operator. Im receiving the error "Expected Model but received RatingPredictor". Any tip on how to fix that, or another way to do it in Rapidminer?

[X-Validation operator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0vyAe.png)

Comment: What is the type of the operator whose title starts with Item Attribute?

Comment: It's the Item Attribute k-NN for Rating Prediction

Answer (score 0):

This is from the Recommender System extension which is not installed by default with the base product so I haven't tried it.

It looks like the `Apply Model` operator requires additional inputs and it also looks like the `Item Attribute...` operator produces something that is not compatible with what RapidMiner is expecting in the context of the `X-Validation`.

My suggestion is to connect the `Mod` output to the first `thr` output in the training side of the `X-Validation`. Then the first `thr` on the testing side should be connected to the `Mod` input of the `Apply` operator. It looks like the operators need additional inputs and outputs to be connected. This can be done with additional `thr` ports that will appear once the first one is used.

One problem will be the lack of a valid `mod` (note the lower case). My suggestion is to use any other operator that produces a valid model on the training side, contrive to feed this some data and possibly contrive to consume it on the test side with a dummy traditional `Apply Model` operator.

I have not tried this so there is no way for me to know whether it will work.